# Calling a JavaScript function in PHP for a website

Tags: javascript, php, html

First of all, thanks for even taking the time to look over my problem.

I have created a program to display the local weather, time and location of the user using an API while fetching their IP adress. The code works absolutely fine when I have a .html file, but as I want to put this on a website, I have made it into a .php file, which I will include in my other php files.

As soon as I change the extension of the file to .php, my code stops working. I am a novice to programming so was hoping you could understand why since I have not had any success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style>
body {
    font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace
}
p { 
    display: inline;
     }
#fps
 {
      display: inline; 
}

</style>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.4/jstz.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready(function () { 
            var cityOut = document.getElementById('city');
 
            fetch('http://ip-api.com/json/')
            .then( res => res.json())
            .then(response => {
                cityOut.innerHTML = response.city + ', ' + response.country;
            })
            .catch((data, status) => {
                console.log('Request failed');
            })

            var fpsOut = document.getElementById('fps');
            setInterval(function () {
                var d = new Date(); 
                fpsOut.innerHTML = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds();
            }, 1000);

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

        });

        function success(pos) {
        var weather = document.getElementById('weather');
        var crd = pos.coords;

        console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
        console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
        
        fetch('https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat='+crd.latitude+'&lon='+crd.longitude)
            .then( res => res.json())
            .then(response => {
                weather.innerHTML = response.main.temp;
            })
            .catch((data, status) => {
                console.log('Request failed');
            })
        }
        function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
</script>

</head>
  
<body>
    
    
   <p>Current Local Time:</p>
    <div id="fps"></div>
   <div id="city"></div>
 <div id="weather"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oscar php can only run on a server, the file is not a server yet the code wouldn't work properly

Comment: Ahhh I see! So does that mean that when I have uploaded the file to the website it should work properly?

Comment: yeah it should work properly on the server

Comment: great, thanks Rilla!